# Podio get form API - Order form fields

Tags: php, forms, podio

I am using Podio-API to fetch a web form's fields in my php web application.

Podio - Get form docs: https://developers.podio.com/doc/forms/get-form-53754

Using the PHP Podio library, I am fetching the podio web form as follows:

```
$webForm = PodioForm::get($form_id);

$fields = $webForm->fields;
```

Here the form fields are NOT ORDERED, as set in the web form. Is there any way to order the form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podio doesn't store order of fields in webform. That order will always match order of fields in app.

So, if in app we have fields: `text1` `text2` `category1` `category2`
And in webform only some fields are enabled: `text1` `category2`

Then code:

```
$webForm = PodioForm::get($form_id);
$fields = $webForm->fields;
```

will return only `text1` and `category2` fields (in any order).

---

And if you want to display fields in same order as webform will do, then you need to read app settings and get list of fields from app and pay attention to `delta` setting from field's config.

Description for `delta` setting is here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349

```
"delta": An integer indicating the order of the field compared to other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me 5mins to found answer in docs :) http://podio.github.io/podio-php/items/

**Sorting items**

You can sort items by various properties. [See a full list in the API reference](https://developers.podio.com/doc/filters).

```
// Sort by last edit date for the items, descending
$collection = PodioItem::filter(123, array(
  'sort_by' => 'last_edit_on',
  'sort_desc' => true
));
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find PodioForm fields, not the podio item fields :)